# Ionic3 Android 8.0 Geolocation is not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i have tested Geolocation on my REAL Android Phone. Here is my Phone information.

Brand: One Plus 5T
Android Version: 8.0.0

High Accuracy has been enable , It work for other Android Phones, but no this.
Could somebody give me a hint what problem is it.

Comment: What geolocation plugin are you using and are you attempting to retrieve location in the foreground or background?

Comment: I am using Native plugin. I was getting the location when the app running, but for this phone always empty until time out, I have try other Android 8.0.0 or other version Android Phones, only my phone has this issue.